# MATLAB program to estimate the energy spectrum

Tags: matlab

MATLAB program to estimate the energy spectrum by non-parametric and parametric methods in the case of EEG signals from epilepsy patients with focal and non-focal area recordings

I have to do this and I have no idea where to start. I have this reference link, https://www.upf.edu/web/ntsa/downloads/-/asset_publisher/xvT6E4pczrBw/content/2012-nonrandomness-nonlinear-dependence-and-nonstationarity-of-electroencephalographic-recordings-from-epilepsy-patients?inheritRedirect=false&redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.upf.edu%2Fweb%2Fntsa%2Fdownloads%3Fp_p_id%3D101_INSTANCE_xvT6E4pczrBw%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26p_p_col_id%3Dcolumn-1%26p_p_col_count%3D1#.X751wmUzaUk

If someone can give me some advice, please.

Answer (score 0):

I have done both.  The Signal Processing Toolbox and System Identification Toolbox documentation is very good on this topic.
[Here is a paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/20581715/) I published on this topic. It is about point process rather than continuous signals, but it does have sections on parametric versus non-parametric spectrum analysis.
Non-parametric is the normal way. If your algorithm uses the fast Fourier transform, it is non-parametric.
Parametric means poles-and-zeroes type models. Spectra estimated non-parametrically tend to be a lot smoother than non-parametric. A key question that arises in parametric estimation which does not arise in non-parametric is what model structure to use and what model order.  In non-paramtric, those questions do not arise.  There are ways to answer those questions.  The Akaike information criterion (AIC) is a standard way to answer the question about model order, although there are certainly alternatives to AIC which are better in some situations.
As you read the documentation, you will see numerous references to 'estimation'. This may seem strange at first, but it is a very important concept: wen you determine the spectrum from a signal, whether you do it parametrically or non-parametrically, you are estimating the true underlying spectrum, based on a sample of the process. The data you recorded is that sample.